# How do I use php to extract data from thingspeak xml containing a type="array"

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am using this code to extract field data from a thingspeak xml stream

```
$url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/203731/feeds.xml?results=500";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$channel_name = $xml->name; 
print_r($channel_name);
foreach ($xml->feeds as $feed) {
    print_r($field1);
}
```

The channel_name displays but not the field1. 
I can't find answers on this site that specifically show extracting data from a type="array" within an xml file
Here is the edited version of the xml returned from thingspeak that shows the feeds records
     "   
     "      Pothole Locations
     "      
     "        
     "          1.00
     "          2.00
     "        
     "        
     "          1.00
     "          2.00
     "        
     "     
     "

Comment: What did you tried? There so many ways to get it out.

Comment: Here is the code I tried using aconnelly's suggestion. It displays the channel_name but no field1 data

Comment: $url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/203731/feeds.xml?results=500";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
//print_r($xml);
//$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
$channel_name = (string) $xml->name; 
print_r($channel_name);


foreach ($xml->feeds as $feed) {
    print_r($field1);
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach ($xml->feeds as $feed) {
    ....
}
```

or for an actual array

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
```